# Create an API Gateway Proxy Resource using SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless, aws-sam, serverless-application-model

I have an apparently-simple requirement to create a proxy resource in SAM (Amazon's Serverless Application Model). So simple in fact that Amazon's documentation appears to leave this as an [exercise](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/blame/4259a52c51a8b22894bcc437f0b0da3571f0d61f/samcli/local/init/templates/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-nodejs/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/README.md#L144) to the reader!

I want to create an AWS API Gateway catch-all endpoint to proxy everything to another HTTP service.

In the AWS Console, the configuration I am trying to build looks as follows:

[image]

I have seen this excellent [post](https://cjohansen.no/aws-apigw-proxy-cloudformation/) by Christian Johansen and his related Stack Overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47757482/aws-api-gateway-proxy-resource-using-cloudformation) for how to do the same thing in CloudFormation. I suppose I could just use that code in SAM, however, SAM has its implicit and explicit APIs, so I want to avoid creating explicit resources if the "right way" is to refer to implicit resources.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, I believe I found the answer in an example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/16988e44caae50812cea1f954f38a8469a074d6a/examples/2016-10-31/implicit_api_settings/template.yaml#L49-L53). The diff relative to the Hello World example that SAM sets up for you out of the box is:

```
diff --git a/sam-app/template.yaml b/sam-app/template.yaml
index 02cd901..f349dcc 100644
--- a/sam-app/template.yaml
+++ b/sam-app/template.yaml
@@ -17,11 +17,11 @@ Resources:
         Variables:
           PARAM1: VALUE
       Events:
-        HelloWorld:
+        ProxyApiGreedy:
           Type: Api
           Properties:
-            Path: /hello
-            Method: get
+            Path: /{proxy+}
+            Method: ANY
 Outputs:
   HelloWorldApi:
     Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
```

In other words, like this:

```
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      ...
      Events:
        ProxyApiGreedy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
```

Comment: You say "I want to create an AWS API Gateway catch-all endpoint to proxy everything to another HTTP service.". However, this solution creates an integration with Lambda, not another HTTP endpoint. So how to create a simple HTTP Proxy integration to another HTTP endpoint?