# API Gateway HTTP Proxy integration with aws-sam (NOT Lambda Proxy)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to use aws-sam to develop / simulate my API Gateway locally. My API gateway makes liberal use of the [HTTP proxy integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html). The production Resource looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of an HTTP Proxy integration on an API Gateway Resource Method]

All of the aws-sam examples [which](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/16988e44caae50812cea1f954f38a8469a074d6a/examples/apps/api-gateway-authorizer-nodejs/template.yaml) [I've](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/16988e44caae50812cea1f954f38a8469a074d6a/examples/apps/api-gateway-authorizer-python/template.yaml) [found](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/16988e44caae50812cea1f954f38a8469a074d6a/examples/apps/api-gateway-multiple-origin-cors/template.yaml), as well as related documentation and [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385621/create-an-api-gateway-proxy-resource-using-sam), use the Lambda integrations / have a hard dependency on a Lambda function being the proxied resource, versus an HTTP Proxy integration.

**Is there a way to define an HTTP Proxy resource for an aws-sam application?** (As opposed to a Lambda Proxy resource?)

Related:

- [Create an API Gateway Proxy Resource using SAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385621/create-an-api-gateway-proxy-resource-using-sam)
- *I am also attempting to solve the same problem using serverless-offline, at the following post - [API Gateway HTTP Proxy integration with serverless-offline (as opposed to a Lambda Proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129644/api-gateway-http-proxy-integration-with-serverless-offline-as-opposed-to-a-lamb)*

Answer (score 5):

Yes, SAM is just a Cloud Formation transform. So you can still create traditional CloudFormation objects as usual. You might be able to also attach it to your Serverless::API but I am less confident about that.

```
Resource:
  Api:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi'
    Properties:
      Description: A test API
      Name: MyRestAPI

    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt Api.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
```

or possibly (untested):

```
Resource:
  Api:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      Description: A test API
      Name: MyRestAPI

    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::Resource'
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt Api.RootResourceId
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      PathPart: '{proxy+}'
```

Comment: For SAM : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385621/create-an-api-gateway-proxy-resource-using-sam?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

**I tested J.A second suggestion and it works! Thank you.**

```
  MyGalleryApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod

  GetImagesResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyGalleryApi
      ParentId: !GetAtt MyGalleryApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: getImages

  GetImagesMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref MyGalleryApi
      ResourceId: !Ref GetImagesResource
      HttpMethod: GET
      AuthorizationType: AWS_IAM
      Integration:
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
        Uri: https://proxy.com/path/getImages
```

**You can combine both HTTP_PROXY and LAMBA_PROXY together in one template by using `RestApiId` in your function definition:**

```
  NonceFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/nonce.handler
      Role: !GetAtt MyGalleryLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      MemorySize: 256
      Description: Nonce function to start authentication
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
            TableName: !Ref UsersTable
      Environment:
        Variables:
          USERTABLE_NAME: !Ref UsersTable
      Events:
        ApiEvent:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /nonce
            Method: GET
            RestApiId: !Ref MyGalleryApi
            RequestParameters:
              - method.request.path.address:
                  Required: True
```