# API Gateway HTTP Proxy integration with serverless-offline (NOT Lambda Proxy)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-offline

I am trying to use serverless-offline to develop / simulate my API Gateway locally. My API gateway makes liberal use of the [HTTP proxy integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html). The production Resource looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of an HTTP Proxy integration on an API Gateway Resource Method]

I have created a serverless-offline configuration based on a few documents and discussion which say that it is possible to define an HTTP Proxy integration using Cloud Formation configuration:

- [httpProxyWithApiGateway.md](https://gist.github.com/og24715/31abb1782ea9d3cc3132d443eb252075) - Setting an HTTP Proxy on API Gateway by using Serverless framework.
- [Setting an HTTP Proxy on API Gateway](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#setting-an-http-proxy-on-api-gateway) (official Serverless docs: API Gateway)

I have adapted the above two configuration examples for my purposes, see below.

Have any tips, for what I might be doing wrong here?

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

service: company-apig
provider:
  name: aws
  stage: dev
  runtime: python2.7

resources:
  Resources:

    # Parent APIG RestApi
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: company-apig
        Description: 'The main entry point of the APIG'

    # Resource /endpoint
    EndpointResource:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Fn::GetAtt:
            - ApiGatewayRestApi
            - RootResourceId
        PathPart: 'endpoint'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    # Resource /endpoint/{proxy+}
    EndpointProxyPath:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
      Properties:
        ParentId:
          Ref: EndpointResource
        PathPart: '{proxy+}'
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi

    # Method ANY /endpoint/{proxy+}
    EndpointProxyAnyMethod:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
      Properties:
        AuthorizationType: NONE
        HttpMethod: ANY
        Integration:
          IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
          Type: HTTP_PROXY
          Uri: http://endpoint.company.cool/{proxy}
          PassthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_MATCH
        MethodResponses:
          - StatusCode: 200
        ResourceId:
          Ref: EndpointProxyPath
        RestApiId:
          Ref: ApiGatewayRestApi
```

For the above configuration, I get this output. Apparently, the configuration registers no routes at all.

```json
{
  "statusCode":404,
  "error":"Serverless-offline: route not found.",
  "currentRoute":"get - /endpoint/ping",
  "existingRoutes":[]
}
```

*Related: I am also attempting to solve the same problem using aws-sam, at the following post - [API Gateway HTTP Proxy integration with aws-sam (NOT Lambda Proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129135/api-gateway-http-proxy-integration-with-aws-sam-as-opposed-to-a-lambda-proxy)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `serverless-offline` doesn't parse your resources for endpoints, enable it via custom config.

```
custom:
  serverless-offline:
    resourceRoutes: true
```

Ends up serving:

```
Serverless: Routes defined in resources:
Serverless: ANY /endpoint/{proxy*} -> http://endpoint.company.cool/{proxy}

Serverless: Offline listening on http://localhost:3000
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline#http-proxy)